# In VS2022 when debugging: Unable to set the next statement. Class not registered

Tags: visual-studio-2022

I am debugging a .NET C# solution in VS2022. Whenever I attempt to set the next statement I get the error message

> Unable to set the next statement. Class not registered.

I am also not able to hot-reload either when I make a change. If I make the slightest change (even just adding some whitespace) and the click on the hot reload button I get the message

> This source file has changed. It no longer matches the version of the
> file used to build the application being debugged.

I appreciate that the second statement is more common but I thought the point of hot-reload was that it recognised that the file had changed and would reload it!

I have found links for the first message but never in combination with the class not being registered.

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: Working with C#

Comment: same issue here :/

Comment: I have the same issue. It started after I upgraded to the latest version of Visual Studio 17.1.6

Comment: I am also on 17.1.6 but I am not sure when this started exactly

Comment: I am using VS 17.1.7, but only noticed this issue starting to crop up when I attempted to upgrade my project to .NET 6.0 from .NET Core 3.1.

Comment: Have it with 17.1.5

Comment: all the same with 17.1.0.

Comment: Suddenly getting this on 17.5.4